# Parallel downloading with urlretrieve

Tags: python, html, parallel-processing, download, urlretrieve

I regularly have to download and rename HTML pages in bulk and wrote this simple code for it a while ago:

```
import shutil
import os
import sys
import socket

socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)   

file_read = open(my_file, "r")
lines = file_read.readlines()
for line in lines:
    try:
        import urllib.request 
        sl = line.strip().split(";")
        url = sl[0]
        newname = str(sl[1])+".html"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, newname)
    except:
        pass
file_read.close()
```

This works well enough for a few hundred websites, but takes waaaaay too long for a larger number of downloads (20-50k). What would be the simplest and best way to speed it up?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python) answer yout question?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q :**
> *<sub>" I **regularly** have to ...
> What would be the **simplest** and **best** way to **speed it up** ? "</sub>*

**A :**
The **SIMPLEST** ( what the commented approach is not ) &
the **BEST** way
is to at least :
 **(a)**
 minimise all overheads ( 50k times `Thread`-instantiation costs being one such class of costs ),
**(b)**
 harness embarrasing independence ( yet, not a being a True-`[PARALLEL]` ) in process-flow
**(c)**
 go as close as possible to bleeding edges of a just-`[CONCURRENT]`, [latency-masked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382#33065382) process-flow

Given
both the simplicity & performance seem to be the measure of "best"-ness:

Any costs, that do not first justify the costs of introducing  themselves by so much increased performance, and second, that do not create additional positive net-effect on [performance ( speed-up )](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bparallelism-amdahl%5D) are performance ANTI-patterns & unforgivable Computer Science sins.

Therefore
I could not promote using GIL-lock (by-design even a just-`[CONCURRENT]`-processing prevented) bound & performance-suffocated step-by-step round-robin stepping of any amount of Python-threads in a one-after-another-after-another-...-re-`[SERIAL]`-ised chain of about `100 [ms]`-quanta of code-interpretation time-blocks a one and only one such Python-thread is being let to run ( where all others are blocked-waiting ... being rather a performance ANTI-pattern, isn't it? ),
so
rather go in for process-based concurrency of work-flow ( performance gains a lot here, for ~ 50k url-fetches, where large hundreds / thousands of [ms]-latencies ( protocol-and-security handshaking setup + remote url-decode + remote content-assembly + remote content-into- protocol-encapsulation + remote-to-local network-flows + local protocol-decode + ... ).

Sketched process-flow framework :

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

MAX_WORKERs = ( n_CPU_cores - 1 )

def main( files_in ):
    """                                                     __doc__
    .INIT worker-processes, each with a split-scope of tasks
    """
    IDs = range( max( 1, MAX_WORKERs ) )
    RES_if_need = Parallel( n_jobs = MAX_WORKERs
                            )(       delayed( block_processor_FUN #-- fun CALLABLE
                                              )( my_file, #---------- fun PAR1
                                                 wPROC    #---------- fun PAR2
                                                 )
                                              for wPROC in IDs
                                     )

def block_processor_FUN( file_with_URLs = None,
                         file_from_PART = 0
                         ):
    """                                                     __doc__
    .OPEN file_with_URLs
    .READ file_from_PART, row-wise - till next part starts
                                   - ref. global MAX_WORKERs
    """
    ...
```

This is the initial Python-interpreter `__main__`-side trick to spawn just-enough worker-processes, that start crawling the `my_file`-"list" of URL-s independently AND an indeed just-`[CONCURENT]`-flow of work starts, one being independent of any other.

The `block_processor_FUN()`, passed by reference to the workers does simlpy open the file, and starts fetching/processing only its "own"-fraction, being  from `( wPROC / MAX_WORKERs )` to `( ( wPROC + 1 ) / MAX_WORKERs )` of it's number of lines.

That **simple**.

If willing to tune-up corner-cases, where some URL may take and takes longer, than one may improve the form of load-balancing fair-queueing, yet at a cost of more complex design ( many process-to-process messaging queues are available ), having a `{ __main__ | main() }`-side FQ/LB-feeder and making worker-processes retrieve their next task from such job-request FQ/LB-facility.

More complex & more robust to uneven distribution of URL-serving durations "across" the `my_file`-ordered list of URL-s to serve.

The choices of levels of simplicity / complexity compromises, that impact the resulting performance / robustness are yours.

For more details you may like to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bparallel-processing%5D) and code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71301969) and there directed examples or [tips for further performace-boosting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bparallel-processing%5D).